# rails 5 api becomes unresponsive in docker setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, docker

EDIT: 
I have tried to move everything out of docker, and exactly the same problem persists. Thus it is NOT a docker issue.

One thing I have noticed is that when things go sour i get the 3 x `SET NAMES..` and `SELECT 'schema_migrations'.'version'` (referenced below). when it works I only get each of them once...what are those are why would they be repeated 3 times?

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

I have a docker-compose development setup with the following containers:
- Rails api
- mysql DB
- redis db
- Resque /rails worker

I have a frontend consuming this based on a local react app.

After months of using this setup without any problems, I suddenly start getting problems... The API becomes unresponsive after a couple of requests...sometimes it is unresponsive at the startup of the rails API.

I don't see any clear errors in any of the servers / containers. The last thing I see in the rails app is:

```
api_1        |    (0.5ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
api_1        |    (1.4ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
api_1        |    (3.9ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
api_1        |    (0.5ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
api_1        |    (17.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
api_1        |    (17.9ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
```

Subsequent requests does not give anything anywhere...nothing in the development.log, no response...just a timeout...no swing outs on memory or cpu consumption 
I have rebuilt the api docker image...

When I check the port on the api server:

```
lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby      6 root    9u  IPv4 459892      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

I can ping internally between the docker containers.

I do not believe that it is the frontend. The it freezes up I have tried making requests with curl and a rest client - same result

EDIT > I have tried running iptraf on the api container, and I do see packets coming in on 172.21.0.1:59644 and then on 172.21.0.6:3000 - the latter being the api server...

EDIT > full output from a curl request:

```
XXX:~$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"admin@mail.com","password":"123"}' -v http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /api/authenticate HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 43
>
* upload completely sent off: 43 out of 43 bytes
```

What am I looking for here?
did anybody have similar experiences?

I have included my docker-compose file below. happy to add anything else - please help

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    env_file: .env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./frontend/public:/www

  db:
    image: mysql
    env_file: .env.dev
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/var/lib/mysql

  redis:
    image: redis
    networks:
      - phototankswarm

  api:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    image: pt-rails:v7
    env_file: .env.dev
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    entrypoint: ./bin/rails.sh
    volumes:
      - /Users/martinhinge/Pictures/docker/phototank:/media/phototank
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis


  resque:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    entrypoint: ./bin/resque.sh
    image: pt-rails:v7
    volumes:
      - /Users/martinhinge/Pictures/docker/phototank:/media/phototank
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - phototankswarm
    links:
      - redis
    env_file: .env.dev

  portainer:
    image:
      portainer/portainer
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      - phototankswarm

networks:
  phototankswarm:
```

Comment: Do you have `"experimental" : true` in your docker daemon config? I've had some weird issues that disappeared when disabling this. I did not look into any details.

Comment: @Grimmy I am running Version 17.06.0-ce-mac19 (18663), Channel: stable, c98c1c25e0. Come to think of it I updated docker recently. I don't remember if the issues started before or after... I have now turned off experiemental...I'll see if this makes it better...thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: Nope turning off experimental features did not help... :-(  problem persists.

Comment: I've fixed issues in the past by deleting all docker networks though `docker network`. Worst case you could try a `docker system prune -a`, but be aware that this wipes everything.

Comment: I'm sure you are also aware of the IO issue on OS X regarding host volumes. Could it be that you trigger some IO-intensive operations that stalls the container?

Comment: @Grimmy not aware of that last bit - Can you throw me a link? the DB is writing data to a host volume which could be intense...

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/77

Comment: I tried the `docker system prune -a`and rebuilt all from bottom up. on first restart the problem showed up...